# spatie laravel data transfer object array of string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-data

Using laravel data to create data transfer objects. I need to declare a property that takes an array of strings.

The post payload will be as follows:

```
{
    "countries": ["en", "de"]
}
```

How do I declare this in the laravel data object. Tried doing this

```
class ExampleData extends Data
{
public function __construct(

    public ?string $someProperty,

    #[DataCollectionOf(string::class)]
    public ?DataCollection $countries) 
    {
    }
}
```

However this throws an error Data collection property countries has an annotation that isn't a data object or is missing an annotation. How can I declare an array of integers or strings in this data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way should be to declare it with an array keyword

```
public ?array $countries
```

The above line works